Running Dockerized Version 4.10.0 or 4.9.3
I am having issues with logging into ProcessMaker after building version 4.9.3 or version 4.10.0 locally. It gives me a Server Error screen and a 500 Internal Server Error in the console.
I'm a newer dev and I am trying to run the Dockerized version of PM locally. I was able to successfully set up and run the dockerized version available here https://github.com/ProcessMaker/pm4core-docker
But when I try to build locally I am running into some issues. I worked through a lot of php version and extension dependency issues with the base local build and am using PHP 8.3, Ubuntu 24.04 and Node 16 and have successfully built PM Version 4.9.3 and 4.10.0. I get to the login screen at localhost:8080 but when I try to login I am given a Server Error screen. The log shows an internal server error 500 so not very helpful. What am I missing? I would be happy to provide more details if someone could guide me in what information would be useful to troubleshoot.
5/11 - update
I'm a newer dev so I will try to give you the debug information I can find, but this is my first time debugging a Dockerized application so I had to spend some time learning how to find the error logs.
I don't think I am generating an actual error, the processmaker error log is not recording a new error. The only error it is showing is for a missing user_sessions table and I was able to resolve that by rerunning the php artisan migrate command in the Docker container.
With APP_DEBUG=TRUE in my .env file, this is the output I am getting when I try to login. It seems like I am logging in successfully but am being rerouted to the login page again. I'm not sure if there is a port issue or a permissions issue, and I am having a hard time finding any error information to troubleshoot further.
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 342 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 366 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 8565 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /css/app.css?id=728f14ddf139150d7ab95a2c567319cd HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /img/processmaker-login.svg?id=0988329da1fc72b469f28fbd82baf6ae HTTP/1.1" 200 4510 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /img/proceC2.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /img/processmaker_do_more.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2?1551f4f60c37af51121f106501f69b80 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/css/app.css?id=728f14ddf139150d7ab95a2c567319cd" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff2?967e123ad65de8c5d5c464071bdb4979 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/css/app.css?id=728f14ddf139150d7ab95a2c567319cd" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /img/new_background.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web-1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [11/May/2024:14:13:02 -0700] "GET /img/favicon.svg?id=fc4895cf2368f5920a6c369a9152bd3e HTTP/1.1" 200 1480 "http://localhost:8080/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

If you give me some direction on what other information or files that would be helpful, I would be happy to provide them.
Thanks!
Katie

Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include debugging errors. No one can help you if you don't give information.

@s4D_t0y I have updated the question with as much information as I could find, please let me know what else I can include that would be helpful and I would be happy to include it.

I found the issue! When the .env file was generated, it populated the SESSION_DOMAIN variable to http://localhost:8080 which was rerouting the application to the login page. I erased the value and left SESSION_DOMAIN blank and this resolved the issue!
SESSION_DOMAIN=

